# How to do multiple aggregate with SINGLE window in Flink?

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm new to Flink, and I want to do something I have done in Spark many times.

For example, in Spark I can do something like below

```scala
ds.groupByKey(???).mapGroups(???) // aggregate 1
  .groupByKey(???).mapGroups(???) // aggregate 2
```

The first aggregate deals with a batch of input data, and the second aggregate deals with the output of the first aggregate. What I need is the output of the second aggregate.

But in Flink, it seems that any aggregate should execute with a specific window like below

```scala
ds.keyBy(???)
  .window(???) // window 1
  .aggregate(???) // aggregate 1
  .keyBy(???)
  .window(???) // window 2
  .aggregate(???) // aggregate 2
```

If I set the window 2, then the input data of the second aggregate may NOT be the output of the first aggregate, which will go against my wish.

I want to do multiple continuous aggregate with the same batch data, which can be gathered in a single window. How to realize it in Flink?

Thanks for your help.

---

Update for more details.

Window must have its own strategy, for example I may set window strategy like below

```scala
ds.keyBy(key1)
  .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.of(1, TimeUnit.HOURS))) // window 1, 1 hour tumbling window
  .aggregate(???) // aggregate 1
  .keyBy(key2)
  .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.of(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES))) // window 2, 1 minute tumbling window
  .aggregate(???) // aggregate 2
```

Window 1 may gather one billion rows in the one hour of tumbling time window, and after aggregate it outputs one million rows.

I want to do some calculation with those one million rows in aggregate 2, but I don't know which window strategy could gather exactly those one million rows.

If I set the window 2 with tumbling time window like above, it may split those one million rows into two batch, and the output of aggregate 2 will not be what I need.

Comment: In the pipeline you have outlined (the one with all the ???), the input to window 2 will be the output of window 1.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks for comment. What troubles me is that the window 2 may split the output of window 1 mistakenly. I have add more details about the input of window 2 in the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this problem by using event-time windows rather than processing-time windows. And if you don't already have timestamps in the events that you want to use as the basis for timing, then you can do something like this in order to use ingestion-time timestamps:

```java
WatermarkStrategy<MyType> watermarkStrategy =
        WatermarkStrategy
            .<MyType>forMonotonousTimestamps()
            .withTimestampAssigner(
                (event, streamRecordTimestamp) -> Instant.now());

DataStream<MyType> timestampedEvents = ds
        .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(watermarkStrategy);

timestampedEvents.keyBy(...)
  .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.of(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)))
  .aggregate(...)
  .keyBy(...)
  .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.of(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)))
  .aggregate(...)
```

This works because the events produced by the first window will each be timestamped with the timestamp for the end of the window they were assigned to. This requires then that the second window's duration be the same as, or a multiple of, the first window's duration.

Similarly, making arbitrary changes to the key-partitioning used by window 2 (compared to window 1) may produce nonsensical results.

Comment: I think this may make the final output comes late? For example if I set both window 1 and 2 with time size of one hour, then the data comes between 1:00 and 2:00 will finally be calculated at 2:00 in the first aggregate, and at 3:00 in the second aggregate. Actually I want them be calculated around 2:00 in the second aggregate(depends on the output num of the first aggregate), just after the first aggregate completes

Comment: If you have two hour-long event time windows, the outputs from the first window will have 1:59:59.999 as their timestamps, and the following window will fire immediately -- it won't wait an hour.